# "Join-Path : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'xxx'"

Tags: powershell, path, appveyor

I have a line in a script that works on my dev environments but not in my Appveyor CI environment.

The script:

```
$rootpath = Join-Path $PSScriptRoot '..' | Resolve-Path

$specs = Join-Path "$rootpath" spec fix *xml | Resolve-Path
```

My dev environment does exactly what I expect: `$specs` is assigned an an array of paths to xml files in that dir.

However, my CI fails out with this:

```
Join-Path : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'fix'.
At C:\projects\myproj-jib50\scripts\Generate-Message-Sources.ps1:8 char:10
+ $specs = Join-Path $rootpath spec fix *xml | Resolve-Path
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Join-Path], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCommand
 
No input files.
```

My dev is powershell 7.3.9, but the CI is 7.3.8.  Could that be the difference?

Comment: are you completely sure you're using 7.3 ? `-AdditionalPath`, the parameter that allows indefinite arguments has been there since LTS which leads to believe that you're using 5.1

Comment: Please include the output of `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()` for both dev and CI platforms.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon You were correct.  See my answer- it appears my CI was not using 7.3.8 in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the CI was not using the version of Powershell that I thought it was using.

The CI is Appveyor using a "Visual Studio 2022" image.

The existing config was using a "ps" section (pre-existing before my involvement) to run powershell commands including my script, and when I altered my script to print out the version within it, it kept printing 1.0.0.  I tried like 3 different ways, and only 1.0.0 came out.  (Could it really be using 1.0.0?  That seems insane.)

However, when I ran `pwsh --Version` outside of that section, I got 7.3.8 (as noted in my question).  Following that lead, I deleted the `ps` section entirely and ran my script with `pwsh`, and it worked correctly.

So it appears @SantiagoSquarzon was correct in his comment-- my CI was not actually using 7.3.8 as I thought.

Answer (score 1):

I would not spend too much time investigating the ci behavior for this case.
Instead I would try to workaround it like this:

```
$specs = $rootpath + '\spec\fix\*xml' | Resolve-Path
```

Comment: `[IO.Path]::Combine` exists as a better workaround than what you're providing in your answer in addition to investigating any issue is never a waste of time.

Comment: Santiago has a point re investigating, but your approach is a viable workaround for Windows PowerShell; it can be simplified to: `Resolve-Path "$rootpath\spec\fix\*xml"`. To ensure use of a file-system-_native_ path, directly expressed _as a string_, use `Convert-Path` instead.